# In pytorch what happens when I move a module to cuda device

Tags: python, pytorch

In an example code I see this:

```py
self.models["pose_encoder"] = \
     networks.ResnetEncoder(18, self.opt.weights_init == "pretrained",
                            num_input_images=self.num_pose_frames)
self.models["pose_encoder"].to("cuda:4")
```

with ResnetEncoder defined by

```py
class ResnetEncoder(nn.Module):
    """Pytorch module for a resnet encoder
    """

    def __init__(self, num_layers, pretrained, num_input_images=1, **kwargs):
        super(ResnetEncoder, self).__init__()
```

I am confused about what happens when the `to(cuda:4)` part happens to the module. Do the whole tensors defined in the module move to cuda:4?
What cause me error now is that I have a member function in the module, and in that function I define a tensor:

```py
def A():
    self.mytensor = []
    # after some operation this is not empty any more
    self.mytensor.cuda()
```

and this error occur:

```
RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:4 and cuda:0!
```

I know the cuda:0 is caused by the .cuda() operation in the last line of code. But I don't know any way to move 'self.mytensor' to cuda:4. I cam pass device as a parameter in the module's constructor, but I guess there is a better way to do this. and I want the device to change during runtime, so I don't want use os.environ also. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Follow [the document](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/cuda.html), `to.device('name_device')` is the special function of `torch.Tensor` which use to move your Tensor to a different device.

The `name_device` can be replaced by: `cuda:num_gpu` or `cpu`, `to.device('cuda:4')` will move the tensor to GPU number 4 (you can check the number of GPU by command `nvidia-smi` on cmd/terminal).

Any operation between two tensors will require they stand in the same device. The bug raises because your `self.mycuda` is on GPU 0, you can move it to GPU 4 by `self.mycuda.to_device('cuda:4')`

**Note:** by using `.cuda() = .to_device('cuda:0')`. You can specify the device by `self.mycuda.cuda(4)`

Comment: Thanks, what I mean is, which tensor will be moved in a module and which will not? does A in the example belong to the module? Why won't it be moved?